# Forward emails to a user

Tags: postfix

I am setting up my first mail server. In the past, I used an already configured Postfix setup that I am trying to replicate.

Essentially I could create a user on the server, then add a rule into /etc/postfix/virtual such as:

```
user@domain.org   user
```

Restart postfix, then send an email to the user and it would work.

I understand there are a lot of factors to get this working properly.

I just tried doing the above, and sending an email to the address I added to /etc/postfix/virtual from the servers shell, and it sent ok, but it didn't arrive in the designated users inbox (which I'm just checking in webmin on the server).

Is there some vital step I have missed here?

Here is an excerpt of the /var/log/maillog:

```
Sep 13 07:58:41 srv sendmail[3037]: r8D6wfEX003037: from=root, size=231, class=0,
nrcpts=1, msgid=<201309130658.r8D6wfEX003037@mydomainserver.org>, relay=root@localhost

Sep 13 07:58:41 srv sendmail[3038]: r8D6wfJa003038: from=<root@mydomainserver.net>,
size=494, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201309130658.r8D6wfEX003037@mydomainserver.net>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]

Sep 13 07:58:41 srv sendmail[3037]: r8D6wfEX003037: to=user@thedomain.org, ctladdr=root
(0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30231, relay=[127.0.0.1]
[127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (r8D6wfJa003038 Message accepted for delivery)

Sep 13 07:58:41 srv sendmail[3040]: r8D6wfJa003038: to=<user@thedomain.org>, ctladdr=
<root@mydomainserver.org> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120494,
relay=thedomain.org. [xx.xx.xxx.xx], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by thedomain.org.
```

Comment: Check the logs to see what happened to the message.

Comment: Thanks for that. With the log above, would I be correct in guessing that it isn't even using postfix? Instead 'esmtp'?

Comment: ESMTP is not an MTA.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. I got it to relay. I didn't have my domain added to local domains :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to ensure you have these directives in your main.cf file:

```
virtual_alias_domains = example.net example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Where example.net and example.com are the domains you want to have virtual maps for.  [See the documentation for details.](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_alias)

If you have a virtual domain in postfix, all the addresses at that domain must be virtual.  If you want to simply redirect mail from one local user to another, you should use normal aliases instead.

Normally, if you just want to have mail to users on your box be delivered to their username at your domain, you don't need to use any kind of aliases at all, and you can simply set your domain in mydestination, and use the `unix:passwd.byname` setting in local_recipient_maps.

Generally `local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_alias_maps`.